# Is there something like a screw-on screw clamp on a hinge?

Tags: tools

I need to fix a wooden board (colored blue in my sketches) to a doorframe (which does not contain a door; colored grey in my sketches). I must not damage the doorframe, and the connection must not be permanent, the board is attached and removed daily.

[image: Doorframe and wooden board]

Usually, I would just use a few screw clamps, but since the board covers the whole doorframe, there is no way to apply pressure from both sides of the doorframe.

Now I imagine something (colored green in my sketches) like a screw clamp where one side is bolted or screwed to the wooden board, so it pulls the board against the doorframe.

[image: Screw clamp screwed onto the board]

However, it would be neat if that screwed-on screw clamp had a hinge, so it can rotate to lie flat against the wooden board when not in use.

[image: On a hinge, so it can rotate?]

Is there something I can use for that, or does anyone have another solution for my problem?

Comment: How strong does the piece have to be held? How much depth does a clamp have to draw against?

Comment: Based on the dimensions of the board, I estimate the whole thing will weigh about 10 to 15 kg. I am planning to hold it in place at four points around the doorframe.  
I don't understand your second question.

Comment: If there is trim around the door, how thick is it? That is what I was referring to as to the depth or thickness of the trim. My weight of it to guess will be about a pound or two using 1X4 and the wedge. The blue board, I don't know how big it is, so I cannot determine it's weight.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll have to make something, but it shouldn't be hard.
 A [spreader clamp](http://www.screwfix.com/p/forge-steel-spreader-clamp-920mm-36/6525d) will do  much of the job.  Many of these have aluminium jaws, which are easy to drill and if necessary tap.  A hinge could then be screwed to the board and to the jaw.

Answer (score 1):

Will this work?
It will hold the piece in place, but be careful if it is supposed to hold a lot of weight or force or ????

[image]

Comment: The hinge would have to be on the other side of the blue board, since the board covers the entire opening. So nothing can go around it. But something like this might work.

Comment: Your sketch looks like it is to hold the blue board on the side of the opening.Is this not the case? Or does the blue board hold a larger piece to cover the opening?